# JSP doesn't compile when starting Jetty on Windows

Tags: java, jetty, jsp-tags

I have recently changed from Linux to Windows. On Linux, Jetty starts with success, but on Windows I have a stacktrace when starting the same application. It seems that Jetty can't compile my JSP.

My JSP contains a specific taglib. When debugging I see that the application finds the taglib but it can't compile it. Here is the stacktrace:

```
    SEVERE: PWC6354: Error occurred while compiling JSP files.  
May 18, 2016 9:25:47 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper loadTagFile
SEVERE: PWC6354: Error occurred while compiling JSP files.  
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.isPackageAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3902)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2241)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1640)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1501)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2302)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2352)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2358)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:498)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2302)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3478)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:250)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:446)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:483)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:373)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
15:25:47,308 WARN  [] ServletHandler       - 
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:483)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:373)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.isPackageAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3902)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2241)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1640)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1501)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2302)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2352)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2358)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:498)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2302)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3478)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:250)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:446)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
    ... 23 more
```

Can anyone help me find the reason for this failure?

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762696/nbsp-breaks-jsp-compilation) help?